# How to call datatype of an input in python

Tags: python, types

I want the output of my code to be ("TypeError") when i typed string on the input instead of Traceback ValueError

```
import math

log = input("log of:")
base = input("with base: ")

print(type(log))

if (int(log)> 0 and int(base)>0):
    log= int(log)
    base = int(base)
    n = math.log(log,base)
    print("log of", log,"with base",base, "is", n)
        
else:
    print("typeerror")
```

But it did not work on this code

Comment: Use `raise TypeError("some error message")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is a special statement that can catch errors, the `try... except...` statement.

What this does is:

> Executes the code in the `try` section of the code.
> On encountering an error it executes the `except` section of the code.

Example:

```
import math

log = input("log of:")
base = input("with base: ")

print(type(log))

try:
    log= int(log)
    base = int(base)
    n = math.log(log,base)
    print("log of", log,"with base",base, "is", n)

except ValueError: # If ValueError occurs.
    print("TypeError") #Prints TypeError
```

For more information see [this.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-try-except/)

Comment: Why not raise a TypeError instead?

Comment: Or better yet, let the ValueError bubble up: that is more Pythonic than catching the ValueError and printing or raising a TypeError.

Comment: He is not trying to raise an error. He is trying to print text in place of the error. Hence the try... except... statement.

Comment: That is better, but this is what he asked for. He might have a different reason for this.

Comment: Yes, but my point is to point out that it's better, more Pythonic, to raise an exception instead. And since Python does that already, just let it be raised by Python instead. People may ask for something because they don't know a more appropriate solution exists.

Comment: Thats what I said, that is better, but he wants to print something in place of that, he might have a reason for that, so I just thought I could tell him that it was possible.